# Assign variable to spelllang in vim script

Tags: vim

im trying to create a vim function to cycle through different spelllang.

```
let g:SpellLanglist= ["en_us", "es"]

let s:lang_index=0
function! SpellLangCycle()
    let l:lang=get(g:SpellLanglist, eval(g:lang_index))
    set spelllang = l:lang
    let g:lang_index = s:lang_index + 1
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>s :call SpellLangCycle()<CR>
```

I dont know how to assign lang variable to spelllang. `set spelllang = l:lang` is not working.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
let &spelllang = l:lang
```

You can set and read contents of an option (such as `spellang`) by using the `&` prefix. (The `set` command doesn't work with dynamic contents or local variables, unless you use `execute` to evaluate a string as a command, but that's much inferior to using `&` to refer to it.)

See [`:help :let-option`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-option) for more details on using `let` with an option.

---

Your script has other issues as well. If you're going to track which language index was last set, you should probably do so in a *per-buffer* variable, since [`'spelllang'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27spelllang%27) is a *per-buffer* option.

You can use `get()` to read that variable but use a default variable if it's unset, which might be really helpful for the first time this code is run in a specific buffer.

You can access an item from the list with a simple `[...]` containing the index.

You also need to "cycle" the variable back to zero once it reaches the last element of the list. You can do so using the `%` operator with the length of the list.

Putting it all together:

```
let g:SpellLanglist= ["en_us", "es"]

function! SpellLangCycle()
    let l:lang_index = get(b:, 'lang_index', -1)
    let l:lang_index = (l:lang_index + 1) % len(g:SpellLanglist)
    let &spelllang = g:SpellLanglist[l:lang_index]
    let b:lang_index = l:lang_index
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>s :call SpellLangCycle()<CR>
```

But I think you can do even better. You don't need an external variable to store the index into the list, you can just look at the current `&spelllang` and find it in the list to find the currently set index.

You can do that with the [`index()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#index%28%29) function. It also returns -1 if the item is not found in the list, which works for us since after we increment it we'll get to the first item on the list.

```
function! SpellLangCycle()
    let l:lang_index = index(g:SpellLanglist, &spelllang)
    let l:lang_index = (l:lang_index + 1) % len(g:SpellLanglist)
    let &spelllang = g:SpellLanglist[l:lang_index]
endfunction
```

One advantage of this approach is that this will always cycle to the *next* language in the list, even if you set `'spelllang'` outside of this function... You can still use it to pick up from the point you set it to, or it will restart from the first one if what you set it to is not on the list.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to accomplish what I was looking for. I really apreciate the tips. I have include this and other similar functionality to this vim plugin https://github.com/asierrayk/vim-toggle